# Открыть окно браузера через Python с профилем, при том что браузер с этим профилем уже запущен

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

С помощью Python и библиотеки Selenium хочу открыть окно браузера chrome с профилем который лежит в папке Default (я про папки профилей в user data от хрома). Но помимо этого профиля у меня есть ещё один профиль(пусть будет профиль #2).

Если я запускаю код при открытом окне профиля #2 или окне профиля #1, то у меня ошибка:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has
> crashed.) Stacktrace:

Если окна закрыты, то код отрабатывает:

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--binary_location=path/chrome.exe')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=path/User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Как можно запустить новое окно с профилем #1 не закрывая открытых окон?